# JQuery Ajax Post + MVC - Error 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

I'm making a find in database when I click in element of table. This call an ajax that receives a mvc route. The problem is I'm getting an error 500 - Internal Server Error.

The Chrome console says error starts in ajax declaration

[image]

My code:

```
table.on('select', function (e, dt, type, indexes) {

    $.ajax({                
        url: settings.mvc.findUserGuest,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (sendDataesult) {
            alert("works! " + sendDataesult);                        
        }                
    });
```

This url route call a function that find a user inside database and return true or false.

Where am I going wrong? How I can this 500 error?

Comment: 500 is reflective of a server side error.  You will need to debug your server side logic to find what error is being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Yea will need to launch debugger in visual studio (or whatever IDE you are using) and debug the method you are calling via ajax.

You will also need to make sure you are using the right return types (ajaxResponse I believe is the correct type)

Also, make sure the variable type you are sending matches the variable type the method is listening for (I use JSON is nearly all cases)